# Consuming actively developed NuGet package

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, nuget-package

First, I will describe our setup (it is an extremely simplified version of the corporate development pipeline). We develop a .NET application, which is dependent on some shared components. The shared components typically develop together with the application. We want turn these shared component to NuGet packages.

So, I publish version 1.0.0.4 of package A and want to consume it in my application. My packages.config looks like this.

```
<package id="A" version="1.0.0.4"/>
```

So far so good. I probably commit packages.config to version control at this point to remember my dependencies. Now I run the next build of package A, which publishes the version 1.0.0.5. Now I want my application to **automatically** update package A to 1.0.0.5 before the build.

However, my packages config now contains an exact verion 1.0.0.4 and it's version-controlled. My questions are:

- Can I somehow specify that I want version 1.0 or higher in packages config? In other words, can I avoid change of packages.config with every new build of every package?
- Can I somehow update the dependencies before build to the the newest version? Can I do it automatically using a script?

I am quite new to NuGet and I come from the ant+ivy/maven world, where this feature is kinid of automatic, so I am still hoping I am missing something obvious in NuGet, although scanning through the discussions on stackoverflow doesn't sound too encouraging.

I've found [Using Nuget in development environment - best practices / how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800525/using-nuget-in-development-environment-best-practices-how-to) and [How to automatically update NuGet packages to latest available version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794907/how-to-automatically-update-nuget-packages-to-latest-available-version) and [NuGet issues with packages.config, project references and the solutionwide packages folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467094/nuget-issues-with-packages-config-project-references-and-the-solutionwide-packa?lq=1), which do not give clear answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `allowedVersions` attribute to automatically use newer package versions within a range, like this:

```
<packages>
    <package id="SomePackage" version="2.1.0" allowedVersions="[2,3)" />
</packages>
```

In this example, any package from the 2.x series will be used, but not from the 3.x series. You can be more specific with the contraint e.g. `allowedVersions="[2.1,2.4)" if you wanted to take any package from 2.1, 2.2, and 2.3 but not 2.4.

See http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning for more details

Comment: IMHO it is not possible. This link speaks about **nuspec** syntax _not_ about **packages.config** syntax. So the allowedVersions atribute is not allowed in packages.config.

Comment: It is definitely possible to specify `allowedVersions` in `packages.config`: "NuGet supports constraining the range of versions that packages can be upgraded to by hand editing the packages.config file using the allowedVersions attribute." http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning#Constraining_Upgrades_To_Allowed_Versions
I have been using this for 2+ years :)

Comment: @MatthewSkelton could you give an example of what your packages.config and .csproj file looks like when consuming a package like this? I am trying to implement something very similar where we consume the nightly build of a NuGet package and have not been able to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the `packages.config` to implicitly allow a higher version. Also, the project files have references to the packages folder which include the package version in the path, so those need to be changed after a package update.

You can perform an update of the `packages.config` and the projects files by running `nuget update`.

You could automate this in the nightly builds and checking in the resulting changes as well. However, it's debatable whether that's a good idea. At the minimum, you should gate the update operations by running a build to make sure the new version doesn't cause a build break.

Comment: We were inclined to do something like this. However, our packages are updated more often than once a day, so the update script would need to be run with every submit. I hoped there would be an easier solution.